# Reading x-access-Level header for Twitter REST API using omniauth-twitter / twitter Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, twitter, twitter-oauth

I'm using Omniauth to authenticate users with Twitter through OAuth (using `omniauth-twitter` gem). I plan to allow normal users to login with just 'read' permissions, and only authorise 'read-write' permissions if/when they decide to create things within the site.

In my `Identity` model I'm analysing the `AuthHash` omniauth passes to the create_with_omniauth action, and I'm making separate logic for each provider type, so that I can look deeper into the returned hash schema if necessary.

If I `raise auth.to_yaml` to output the structure, I see the 'x-access-level' header that I'd like to read, but I don't know how to look into the `response: Net::HTTPOK` object in order to get to the next level of the structure.

This is the auth structure, *cutting out some of the unnecessary details*

```
--- !ruby/hash:OmniAuth::AuthHash
provider: twitter
...
extra: !ruby/hash:Hashie::Mash
  ...
  access_token: !ruby/object:OAuth::AccessToken
    ...
    response: !ruby/object:Net::HTTPOK
      http_version: '1.1'
      code: '200'
      message: OK
      header:
        x-access-level:
        - read-write
        x-ratelimit-limit:
        - '350'
        x-ratelimit-remaining:
        - '348'
        x-ratelimit-reset:
        - '1330798604'
```

So far I can get to the response with `auth["extra"]["access_token"].response` but putting `.header` at the end returns the same response structure, and `["header"]` is empty when I raise it.

I'm ok with using the Twitter gem if necessary to do a `verify_credentials` call inside the Identity model (since Twitter adds the x-access-level header to every response, but even with this approach I wouldn't know how to read the returned headers to read the x-access-level header.

Comment: Which way did you go in the end?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't had much time to spend on my own projects since I asked, but the author of the omniauth-twitter gem did make some changes (might be in a branch on his github repo) to try and get it to work. IIRC I tried and couldn't get it to work immediately, but then I didn't have time to work on it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the same ruby twitter client but it might help other that arrive here after looking for the same question with the ruby twitter client (gem "twitter").

So going from this call:

```
twitter_client = Twitter::Client.new(:oauth_token => token, :oauth_token_secret => secret)

twitter_client.verify_credentials
```

That will give you only the user info json. You can actually get the twitter api response and then check the `x-access-level` contained in the header

```
resp = twitter_client.get, "/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json"
resp[:response_headers]["x-access-level"] # "read-write" in my case
```

Hope this helps others...